# Having an error with detecting a mention/userid argument (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I'm trying to script a command that is inspired by the Dyno "-avatar" command that simply creates an embed that responds to command that contains an image URL of your profile picture. I've asked a couple other people and I've replaced my code with their suggestions and I'm still receiving errors, any ideas?
Code group:

```
   if (arguments.length == 1) {
    let userID = args.includes('<@!') ? args.replace('<@!', '').replace('>', '')
        : args.includes('<@') ? args.replace('<@', '').replace('<', '') : '';

    if (userID == ' ') {
        receivedMessage.reply('Invalid user ID or mention.');
        return;
    }

    receivedMessage.guild.cache.fetchMember(userID).then(member => {
        receivedMessage.channel.send({embed: {
            color: 3447003,
            author: {
              name: receivedMessage.author.username,
              icon_url: receivedMessage.author.avatarURL
            },
            title: userID.user.username + "'s" + " Avatar",
            image: {
                url: userID.user.avatarURL(),
            }
        }});   
    }).catch(() => {
        receivedMessage.channel.send('Could not find a member with the given ID or mention!');
    });
}
```

Comment: what errors are you recieving ? wha't's your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the members being mentioned by doing:

```js
message.mentions.users.members;
```

And the first member that is mentioned by doing:

```js
message.mentions.users.members.first();
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out most of my problem was based on the fact that I was doing v11 coding ;-;. I'm still fairly new to this and a lot of tutorials are outdated, so..